# Fast attack, slow release envelope detector

Tags: audio

EE novice here.

I want an envelope follower for a +/- 1V audio signal which immediately (i.e. within a couple of milliseconds, ideally) increases to the amplitude of the input signal, then falls off exponentially (with decay rate adjustable by a pot) as long as the input is below the current output value.

I know how to make a basic envelope follower with diode, resistor, and capacitor but I believe that will have a slow attack response when the RC time is long.

Any pointers for how to approach this?

Comment: Please define `instantly increases` as a proper design can have a wide attack/decay ratio. The key is a low impedance driver and a low 'C' value.

Comment: Ideally within 1-2 ms, but slightly longer might be workable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may work for you. We are not a design house per se, but this would get you a functional minimum and maybe all you need. Your option to use a single ended op-amp but it needs to be a JFET/MOSFET type because the second op-amp (2 per package) is a very high impedance buffer so you can have a long decay time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa4Hbe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I’ll dig in. Is there a standard name for this setup? I didn’t find a lot to go on in my googling.

Comment: I assume I want zero R2 for fastest attack? I don’t need variable attack time, just variable release.

Comment: It is just a **Peak Detector** with adjustable attack and decay. Yes, you can omit the 10K pot, but not the 2.2K.